# How to get the length of a dialog item text?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi

Im trying to get the dialog item text into a buffer. It works with `GetDlgItemText()`, but how do i get the length of the text so i can allocate the buffer before i read it in there? I want to be sure i always get the whole text. I could use always for example 10k buffer, but it would be nicer if there wasnt any chance that the user text isnt received completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the window handle, obtained by calling `GetDlgItem`, a `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message. Or if you prefer call `GetWindowTextLength`.

Comment: GetWindowTextLength() works? ah i see, once again the function names tricked me...